# how to convert Object array to array while single value returning

Tags: php, arrays, object

how to convert Object array to array while single value returning ,
here is the o/p what i am getting while i am getting only one hotel, how can i convert it in a way to access it as a 0th [0] value shown in code. i have problems in accessing when i m getting single hotel in o/p. `print_r($result); via foreach()`

```
    stdClass Object
    (
        [cityId] => 000000000020
        [checkInDate] => 2013-12-20
        [checkOutDate] => 2013-12-21
        [customerId] => 
        [customerAccountType] => SH01
        [customerType] => 
        [currency] => INR
        [noOfRoomsRequested] => 1
        [searchAvailabilityResult] => stdClass Object
            (
                [hotelId] => IXW1
                [hotelName] => Ginger Jamshedpur
            )
   )



===what i want is ================================


       stdClass Object
        (
            [cityId] => 000000000020
            [checkInDate] => 2013-12-20
            [checkOutDate] => 2013-12-21
            [customerId] => 
            [customerAccountType] => SH01
            [customerType] => 
            [currency] => INR
            [noOfRoomsRequested] => 1
            [searchAvailabilityResult] => Array
                (
                      [0] => stdClass Object
                           (
                          [hotelId] => IXW1
                          [hotelName] => Ginger Jamshedpur
                           )
                )
       )
```

Comment: Please add code you use to build "searchAvailabilityResult" field...

Comment: try casting the object to array using `(array)$obj`

Comment: You have only one object in `searchAvailabilityResult`, there will be no array. If you want array of that single element simply write `$mainObj->searchAvailabilityResult = array($mainObj->searchAvailabilityResult)`

Comment: this is o/p of web service , $result is printing this much only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of single value

```
$result->searchAvailabilityResult = array($result->searchAvailabilityResult);
```

Many thanks to #Maciej Sz

Answer (score 0):

$result->searchAvailabilityResult = get_object_vars($result->searchAvailabilityResult);